# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 in hadoop

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, jar, package

I am trying to count the frequency of each word in a text file using hadoop. I have attached the code.

```
package sub4;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.*;
public class count {
    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
        //private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        //private Text word = new Text();


    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] line = value.toString().split(",");
        for(String lines:line) {
            context.write(new Text(lines),one);
        }
    }
    } 

  

public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {          int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }  
  }



  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Configuration conf = new Configuration();
       Job job = new Job(conf, "count");
       job.setJarByClass(count.class);
       job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
       job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
       job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
       job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
       job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);      
       job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);    
       FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
       FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
       job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }        ``
}
```

I saved this code and tried to make it a jar file in eclipse by right clicking it and pressing export. After than I went to terminal and typed hadoop jar /home/user/wcount.jar sub4.count /abc/wc/output.

This error came

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at sub4.count.main(count.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code expects an input file name and an output file name on the command line.

You didn’t provide them.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. This is my first time learning hadoop. So not sure what you mean by it. I have mentioned wcount.jar. Isnt it the file name?

Comment: No.  Look where args is being used.